# How to take image source from code behind after updating it from client side

Tags: asp.net, uploadify

I have the following scenario.

User is trying to update the profile image , I am using uploadify plugin to upload image to server , and in callback I am setting

```
  <img src="" runat="server" class="user-image" id="uploadedImage" />
```

SRC attribute to the uploaded path. This part is working good , then when user clicks on Save button , i need somehow to get new picture path and save it to database.

```
 user.ImageUrl = this.uploadedImage.Attributes["src"];
```

doen't brings a new picture path , and returns a previous path.
Can someone help pls ?

Comment: Do you mean basic html FileUpload control or some third party control? If it is FileUpload control, please make sure to have an ajax call to upload the image in some local folder of your server once user clicks on upload button. If you fail to do this you will not be able to get the file at your server on post back (you cann't access your user files from the server). This should be true for third party controls as well (but not sure so see docs for implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this you may use using hidden field, among other ways.

Please refer to:
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/603102/Persist-JavaScript-changes-on-postback,
http://forums.asp.net/t/1428896.aspx/1,
http://forums.asp.net/t/1285473.aspx.